# Algorithms for solving systems of quadratic multivariate polynomials

Tags: cryptanalysis, multivariate-cryptography

What are the best algorithms for solving systems of $k$ polynomials equations where these are quadratic multivariate polynomials on $k$ variables?

I've encountered such systems on my research and I'm in the position to say if they are somehow solvable or not, and what would be the complexity to run an "attack". I know about linearization and grobner bases but I'm not very sure if these are the best for quadratic mv-polys.